# Array of structure in objective c

Tags: arrays, objective-c, xcode, macos, struct

I have trouble using struct like an array in objective c.

The struct which I use is the following -

```
struct Abc{
__unsafe_unretained NSString *textValue;
BOOL value;
};
```

And what I try to achieve is -

```
 struct Abc *abc;
abc = @{@{abc->textValue:@"hello",abc->value:false},
        @{abc->textValue:@"thank you ",abc->value:true},
        @{abc->textValue:@"welcome",abc->value:true}
      };
```

As I'm very new to objective-c, I needed some help regarding this.

Please do let me know if my code is wrong. **My main concern is to use that struct in an array**. Thank You!

Comment: You need to use objective-c's class with objective-c's array or use c's struct with c's array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up Objective-C and C syntax. `@{ key:value, ... }` is an Objective-C dictionary literal, `@[ a, ... }` is an Objective-C array literal, and `abc->` is part of a C expression to access a field of a `struct` via a pointer to the struct.

In C the syntax `{ a, ... }` serves dual purpose as both an array and struct literal determined by context. Your fragment can be written as:

```
struct Abc abc[] = { {@"hello", false},
                     {@"thank you", true},
                     {@"welcome", true}
                   };
```

which declares `abc` as an array, rather than a pointer. Using an array type with empty bounds (`[]`) sizes the array based on the initializer and the declaration and assignment must be done together.

If you want to stick with your pointer type rather than use an array type you can provided add a cast, producing what C terms a *compound literal*, and in this case you can seperate the declaration from the assignment:

```
struct Abc *abc;
abc = (struct Abc []){ {@"hello", false},
                       {@"thank you", true},
                       {@"welcome", true}
                     };
```

Note: You can't use the cast `(struct Abc *)` here... C initializer and compound literal syntax & semantics are as quirky as is the C(++) way ;-)

Note: It is more usual in Objective-C to use `YES` & `NO` rather than `true` and `false` but the latter are accepted as `BOOL` literals.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for making it clear , I'll first learn all the basic syntax before coding.